# How to create a conditional sum on values being in bold

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, sum

I have a vector in the following form

```
0   -1.93364     
1   **-0.0179182**  
2   1.78019      
3   **0.167775**    
4   0.577237
```

How can i sum the values in bold? how can i create a conditional sum of the values being in bold?

I tried `np.where(df.values == bold)` where `bold = 'font-weight: bold'`  but no success

Answer (score 0):

Well here is one possible solution:

```py
sample = ["-1.93364", "**-0.0179182**", "1.78019", "**0.167775**", "0.577237"]
total = 0
for n in sample:
    if n[:2] == "**" and n[-2:] == "**":
        total += float(n[2:-2])
```

`0.1498568`